# How do I install Ubuntu alongside UEFI enabled Windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, system-installation, uefi

I recently (about a month ago) bought a Dell XPS 8500 Desktop with UEFI enabled Windows 8 Pro pre-installed. I am trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit dualboot with Windows on this computer. I don't know much about UEFI, but I think I followed the correct instructions to do this installation. Here's what I've done so far:

1. I have a 256GB SSD drive with the Windows OS partition and a 1TB drive for data. I created a 100GB partition on the 1TB drive for ubuntu. This was done through Windows Disk Management.
2. I downloaded Ubuntu and created a bootable USB as per the instructions on the Ubuntu website.
3. I tried installing Ubuntu through the USB.

PROBLEM: While installation, I do not see a "Install alongside Windows 8" option like I have usually seen in all my previous installs.

Now, I don't know if this has to do with UEFI and I don't know much about that anyway.

QUESTION: How should I proceed with the installation?

I am currently on the same computer through Windows. I also have access to a laptop with Windows 8 Pro (possibly not enabled with UEFI - it's an old computer with newly installed OS) alongwith Ubuntu 12.10 dualboot.

- Let me also add that my Secure Boot is ON. I also tried it with SecureBoot OFF, but didn't work.
- I followed all the steps mentioned here in order: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

EDIT: I "tried" Ubuntu without installing it via the LiveUSB. It is not able to access any of the drives. Do you think that has anything to do with this issue? Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Eric, I followed all the steps mentioned there in order. For some reason, the LiveUSB is not able to detect the Windows Installation. Note: I had UEFI with SecureBoot ON. I also tried it with SecureBoot OFF, but didn't work.

Comment: Related: [“Install alongside” option missing. How do I install Ubuntu beside Windows using “Something Else”?](http://askubuntu.com/q/163962/40581)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should defragment your Windows partition, as far as I know Windows comes with a tool for that.

Once defragmentation is complete you have to perform a "full shutdown" in Windows, as by default it does like a hibernation when shutting down. To do that search for `cmd` in Windows Search and it will point you to the command line prompt, start it and execute the following command:

```
shutdown /s /t 0
```

Now you have to start a Ubuntu live session by booting a Live-USB and choosing the option: ***Explore Ubuntu without installing***.

When the desktop loads up, start **GParted** and you should see the EFI partition at the start of the partition table followed by your drive `C:\` partition, click on the `C:\` partition and re-size it to make room for Ubuntu partition. Click on the "Apply" button of GParted and wait until it completes the operations.

Now start the Ubuntu Installator, when it prompts you for the installation type you should choose ***Something Else***, the last option.

[image: Installation type]

And now you just select the free space and click the <kbd>+</kbd> button at the bottom.

[image: Disk allocation]

Create the new partition as **Primary** type, using **Ext 4 journaling file system** and setting mounting point to **/**.

[image: Create new partition]

After installation is complete just reboot and check if everything works fine. Although, as your Windows is installed in UEFI mode you can experience problems, such as booting straight to Windows and not passing through GRUB. For problems like that you should use [Ubuntu Boot-Repair tool](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Also check these Q&As if in trouble: [Windows 8 doesn't allow Ubuntu start-up](https://askubuntu.com/q/283574/21195)
 and https://askubuntu.com/a/292783/21195 .

Answer (score 3):

1. Use the Windows tools to shrink your Windows partition.
2. Disable `SecureBoot` in your BIOS
3. Install Ubuntu in the free space via the [Something Else](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall#Installation_type) install option. You will just need to create a `SWAP` partition (few GB), and the rest as `root` partition, see [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace) for more info.
4. Reboot
5. If you cannot access Windows or Ubuntu, run [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair) to fix the GRUB menu.

Comment: Prahar specified that disabling Secure Boot "didn't work," although it's unclear precisely what that means. This could be an important detail. Also, given that Prahar as *already* shrunk the Windows partition, I suggest deleting the to-be-Linux partition that was created in Windows instead of shrinking the Windows partition again.

Comment: Thank you @LovinBuntu. I will go ahead with that option. I am just wondering why my Windows partition is not visible to Ubuntu??

Comment: @Rod By that I meant that even with SecureBoot disabled, the Ubuntu LiveUSB could not identify my Windows partition. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @Prahar I don't know why WIndows is not visible by Ubiquity (the Ubuntu installer), but I have seen many other users with this issue. I recommend you create a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+filebug).

Comment: By "Windows is not visible," do you mean that you simply don't see an "install alongside" option, or do you mean that when you select the "something else" option, the disk shows up as unpartitioned? If the former, then you should do as LovinBuntu suggests and use the "something else" option. If that option shows no partitions, though, then that's an indication that libparted, upon which the Ubuntu installer relies, doesn't like your partition table. In that case, you'll need to fix the problem, probably with [`gdisk`](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html).

Comment: @LovinBuntu - Do you think this has anything to do with the SSD?

Answer (score 0):

you should reboot - then go to bios-mode (with F2 or else F-key - depends on vendor)

there enable efi - and not uefi.
exit and save.

reboot and try to install ubuntu again.

here are more informations:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I do not have a EFI mode. There is only UEFI mode and it is already enabled

Comment: in recent computers, EFI means UEFI.

Comment: UEFI refers to EFI version 2.x. The vast majority of PCs sold today support UEFI, but some use "EFI" in their firmware settings. Macs still use EFI 1.x, although Apple has moved several UEFI/EFI 2.x features into its version of EFI 1.x. For most Linux purposes, the differences between EFI 1.x and UEFI/EFI 2.x are unimportant. Thus, "EFI" vs. "UEFI" in the firmware is an unimportant distinction.