# Installation of Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 on Sony Vaio SVF15218SN

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, vaio

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 on my Sony Vaio SVF15218SN laptop, but I am unable to boot Ubuntu. I disabled the Secure Boot option. Please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Please give more information. What did you try, what went wrong? Walk us through step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at the following Official link to Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows Operating system.

[Dual boot Ubuntu with Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit troublesome to install Ubuntu after Installing Windows 8 , Because of [UEFI](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) .

[Link for Pre Installed 8](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported) , 
[Other Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302680/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-uefi-enabled-windows-8-on-a-dell-xps-8500)
I advise you to Install Ubuntu then 8 [Link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)