# Installing Ubuntu 13.04 along Windows 8 on acer predator

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 alongside an existing Windows 8 installation. I have shrunk the existing partition where windows is installed in order to make room for Ubuntu.

I booted Ubuntu with the live DVD and it boots without any problem. I then launch the installer, which then probes for existing OS installations on the system. The overview I get mentions my partitions, but it doesn't detect any installed operating system. So I fear that if I continue to install Ubuntu by manually selecting the room where a new partition can be created, my computer will be messed-up.

My computer is UEFI-enabled so I thought the problem could be there. I disabled SecureBoot and activated the option to always launch in CSM modus (which makes the system behave like on older BIOS modus?)

When looking in gparted, I can also so all my partitions.

Does anybody have any idea how come the installer doesn't detect my windows 8? I should mention that there are quite a lot of partitions on the first disk (I think 4 or 5), maybe that's a cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below threads which explains more;

- [**Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- [**How do I install Ubuntu alongside UEFI enabled Windows 8 on a Dell XPS 8500?**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302680/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-uefi-enabled-windows-8-on-a-dell-xps-8500)