# problem installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I want to install Ubuntu 14.04 on a system with Windows 8 already installed. I do not get the option of "install beside windows". It shows that all of my drive is free space and unpartitioned whereas in Disk application I can see my partitions.

`sudo fdisk -l`  result:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd087a632

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      718847      358400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          718848   409602047   204441600    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       409602048  1748721663   669559808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 8054 MB, 8054112256 bytes
256 heads, 29 sectors/track, 2118 cylinders, total 15730688 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        4184    15730687     7863252    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Start the Ubuntu install media then select "Try Ubuntu". After that run `sudo fdisk -l` (its an "l" at the end of the command not the number "1") in a Terminal and [add the output to your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/472871/edit)

Comment: Does [this answer about free space](http://askubuntu.com/questions/431278/no-install-ubuntu-13-10-alongside-windows-8-option-available-in-the-installer-w#431280) help? Also did you do a "full shutdown" in Windows? See [How do I install Ubuntu alongside UEFI enabled Windows 8](http://askubuntu.com/questions/302680/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-uefi-enabled-windows-8-on-a-dell-xps-8500).

Comment: @bain in gparted i see only 931.51 GiB unallocated
again i say that i can see my partitions in Disk application

Comment: @bain one more thing in terminal when i type `sudo gparted /dev/sda1` i can see the partition but when i try sda instead of sda1 i get what i say in last comment

Comment: Doing `gparted /dev/sda1` makes no sense, sda1 is a partition not a drive. Did you try the solution suggested in the other answer? "Normally Ubuntu installer doesn't see unallocated space.You have to create ext4 partition from that unallocated space."

Comment: @bain so then what happens to my windows?

Comment: Nothing, as long as you do not delete the partition or tell the installer to overwrite it with Ubuntu. If you don't want Ubuntu to help you with the partitioning, just select manual partitioning and create a new partition in the unallocated space.

Comment: @bain i tried for format my free space as ext4 but i get error
Error creating partition on /dev/sda

Comment: Try making a logical partition,then add your ext4 partitions inside it.

Comment: @bain is there any way to format my entire hard and repartition it again?

Comment: Of course, but you will lose all of your existing data.

Comment: @bain i already lost them can you please tell me how to repartition it with priority of windows?

Comment: The simplest scheme is 3 partitions - Linux /, Linux swap, and windows. Create and format the partitions using gparted from the installer, then boot Windows and install to the chosen partition, then boot Ubuntu, choose manual install, and assign / and swap to your chosen partitions. For more detailed instructions see [Multiple OS Installation](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Multiple_OS_Installation)