# Can't boot to Ubuntu directly

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I use a HP Pavilion machine with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 in dual boot. Whenever i start the system, it boots to windows. I tried to use

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

from Windows as I saw in this link. [Grub not showing on startup for Windows 8.1 Ubuntu 13.10 Dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371559/grub-not-showing-on-startup-for-windows-8-1-ubuntu-13-10-dual-boot). What I ended up with is multiple entries of Ubuntu in Boot Device Options of my BIOS. Clicking one of those boots me to Ubuntu. Now I don't know why I see this list is increasing. The last time I booted in I saw 7 entries. I don't understand any thing what is happening. Please help. Everytime i boot to Windows this list increases.[BIOS Boot Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GB3U1.jpg)

[image: BIOS Boot Manager]

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Boot into Windows operating system, open **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

In case Fast Boot is enabled in your configuration:
Open **Windows Control Panel** -> **Power Settings**.
Enable **show hidden settings** - uncheck **Fast Boot**.

**Shutdown** the machine completely, do NOT reboot.

**Step 2**

Boot from Windows installation media, on **Install now** screen select **Repair your computer**.

Choose **Command prompt** and execute:

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot  
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

**Step 3**

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**.

When the Ubuntu Live desktop appears, open a terminal and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd*** /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sd** /mnt/boot/efi
for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do sudo mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sd*
update-grub
```

Note:

`sd*` = disk | `sd**` = efi partition | `sd***` = system partition

To identify the partition numbers use GParted - it is included in the Ubuntu installation media.

Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in UEFI settings to be the default operating system to boot.

Now you can boot Ubuntu directly or select the Windows environment from GRUB boot menu.

**Update (instructions on how to rebuild everything as you asked for this in your comment) :**

Boot into BIOS and enable UEFI mode and then (in case there is an option)  disable Secure Boot.
Boot from Ubuntu install media and open GParted ... create a new partition table - choose GPT.
Install Windows - boot into Windows and disable Fast Boot and Hibernation  - shutdown the PC.

Boot from Ubuntu install media - open GParted and shrink the Windows partition.
Create a new partition from the unallocated space and format it with ext4.
Create another new partition and format this one with linux-swap.

Close GParted and start the Ubuntu installer - when asked choose Something else.
Select the ext4 partition you created before and choose **/** (root) as mount point.
When Ubuntu is installed, boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu as default system.

Comment: sir, after i performed the steps those entries have reduced to two. But i don't find any UEFI settings. I see an UEFI boot order with the entries as         1.Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive  2.USB Diskette on Key/USB Hard Disk  3.USB CD/DVD ROM Drive  4.OS Boot Manager. I don't understand what should be the correct sequence...

Comment: @AngshumanGhosh : You have to access the BIOS by pressing one of the F keys (the key is a different one depending on PC vendor models) and change the boot order in the settings there to make it permanently. You have to set the Ubuntu operating system entry to be the first boot option in the boot order sequence.

Comment: Can you please elaborate "Ubuntu operating system entry". I don't find anything as such in my UEFI settings throughout. The UEFI Boot Order is set as I mentioned before with legacy support enabled.

Comment: @AngshumanGhosh : Legacy support ? Where did you mention this ? Did you install Ubuntu in legacy mode ? Try to disable Legacy mode and enable EFI mode ! Press the F10 key (screenshot) immediately after starting the PC to access the BIOS and change settings. There must be an Ubuntu boot option. :)

Comment: I don't see any Ubuntu option.. surely, I searched entire of the UEFI settings. The only possible way to boot to Ubuntu is by going to **Boot Device Options** within my BIOS and then clicking on one of those ubuntu options(screenshot). I would like to completely format my disk and dual boot once again. Kindly can you give me the correct steps(any video link or anything). I'm having an **Insyde F.26** uefi.  I hope this will solve all these issues.

Comment: @AngshumanGhosh : I updated the answer with instructions on how to rebuild everything from scratch. :)

Comment: Previosly when I installed Ubuntu I did all the steps. But the problem continues. It is same as this (http://askubuntu.com/questions/493397/dual-boot-install-of-trusty-ubuntu-on-an-hp-with-windows-8-64-bit-pre-installe)

Comment: @AngshumanGhosh : It seems that this is a HP BIOS related problem. Please try out whether it works after following the instructions given in the update of my answer. If the issue is still present afterwards, you should contact HP. Good luck ! :)