# Dual Boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed windows 8.1 after installing Ubuntu on my laptop .. so Ubuntu disappeared from boot menu ...  I used EasyBCD and added a new entry ..

But still doesn't work .. when I restart my laptop the boot menu shows Ubuntu .. but by clicking on it the laptop restarts then black screen appears with a "_" blinking ..

[image]

Any help to recover Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried using grub customiser form the live cd?

Comment: Your BIOS is in UEFI mode? Take a look at this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/302680/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-uefi-enabled-windows-8

Answer (score 0):

You could try reinstalling GRUB into the MBR (Master Boot Record) of your hard drive.
To do that, you will need an Ubuntu live CD/USB stick.

There are many tutorials available online, f.e. [this one](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd).